# CodeIgniter - getting the site url prefixed to some anchor tags

Tags: codeigniter

I've inherited a project which is just a intranet document storage type of site. There's a drop down list of categories and a table that gets filled with the different documents associated with those categories. When an option in the drop down is selected jQuery captures it and uses ajax to build a querystring (a CI happy URL) and then it eventually returns a string that is the html for a

I get this back:

<tr><td class='fileName'><a href='xxxxxx.xxxxxx.com/salesadmin/Education/Education-Collection-Process-and-Chargeback-Policy.doc' target='_blank'>Education Collection Process and Chargeback Policy</a><p class='fileDescription'></p></td><td class='fileExtension'><p class=doc>doc</p></td><td class='fileModed'>2010-08-10 07:52:30</td><td class='btn'><a class='btnEditLine' name='5' href='javascript:' title='Click to EDIT: "Education Collection Process and Chargeback Policy"'>Edit</a></td><td class='btn'><a class='btnDeleteLine' name='5' href='javascript:' title='Click to DELETE: "Education Collection Process and Chargeback Policy"'>Delete</a></td></tr>

The href is correct, it is pointing to where the downloadable files are located. But for some reason when I roll over the links in the browser they are being prefixed with the site url:

http://kopmacwwwo1.xxxxxxx.com/InternalAdmin/admin/index/xxxxxx.xxxxxx.com/salesadmin/Education/Education-Collection-Process-and-Chargeback-Policy.doc

I console.log everything right up to where it is inserted into the tbody and it is correct. Is this something CI is doing and if so how do I correct it?

Thanks

Edit: JS Function that is making the ajax call:

```
// ajax request triggered by catagory drop down menu selection or by other functions
    getCatagoriesItems: function ()
    {

        // call function in master.js file to block the whole web page using blockUI
        blockPage();

        // unbind previous evant handlers to edit and delete buttons to free memory (not sure if you have to do this, but better safe than sorry)
        $(".btnEditLine").unbind();
        $(".btnDeleteLine").unbind();

        // get base url of current site
        var baseurl = $("#site_url_for_ajax").val();

        // get admin type
        var adminType = $("#admin_type").val()

        // get catagory id
        var catID = $("#catagoryDropDownList option:selected").attr("id");

        // get the id of the selected item from the drop down list. This will correspond with the table name in the database
        var queryString = baseurl + "admin/ajaxCatagorySelection/" + catID + "/" + adminType;


        // run AJAX GET
        $.get(queryString, function(data)
        {
            // push data into obj var
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            // dump data into table when request is successful
            $("#dataResultsTable tbody").html(JSONParser.parseAdminDropDownSelectedJSON(obj));

            // rebind event handlers to edit buttons
            bindEditButtonEventListener();

            // rebind event handlers to delete buttons
            bindDeleteButtonEventHandler();

            // unblock page when done
            $.unblockUI();
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use `site_url()` or `anchor()`? As described [HERE](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) they both prefix the site url from the config file.

Comment: No, the only thing I could find in his code was in the master_header file there's a hidden input with a $site_url_for_ajax var, which is the base url for the site. I couldn't find where he was setting that variable, is that a CI default?

Comment: I should add here when the site is first loaded it accesses a general category and those links are coming out fine. This is only occurring when an AJAX call is made, which of course is going to happen 99% of the time on the site. : D

Comment: This is just a guess, but I think this might be a browser issue. I think that since your link does not seem to begin with `http://` then your browser will prepend the url. If I just look at a simple page I happen to have open I have a link like `href=page.html` and that is displayed in a roll-over as `href="http://server.name/page.html"`. Other than that, I'm afraid I don't have much more to offer other than to say that I have not seen a `$site_url_for_ajax` variable before, but I am by no means a CI expert.